# Salesforce Bulk API Upsert

Tags: api, bulk

Iam using Salesforce Bulk API to upsert  records from my application to salesforce. I have a confusion in Upsert.Now I already have a account named XYZ in salesforce .I create an external id as myexternalid_c. Now I send my json data with XYZ account (Along with external ID) from my application.Will duplicate be avoided.If so can Any one explain the logic how salesforce deals with it

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_examples_upsert.htm

Answer (score 1):

The records you are upserting can be matched against a Id or a external Id field.

Below is a excerpt from salesforce documentation:

> Upsert uses the external ID to determine whether it should create a
>   new record or update an existing one:
>
> - If the external ID is not matched, then a new record is created.
> - If the external ID is matched once, then the existing record is    updated.
> - If the external ID is matched multiple times, then an error is    reported.
> - When batch updating multiple records where the external ID is the    same for two or more records in your batch call, those records will
>     be marked as errors in the UpsertResult file. The records will be
>     neither created or updated.

Also, a nice [blog](http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/all-about-upsert-and-external-id-in-dataloader-and-apex-videos/) has been written on the working. Hope this helps.